# how to add subscript(or superscript) in notion block？

Tags: subscript

i am new in using notion as a notebook.Before this,i use oneNote instead,because i found that notion is more convinient in same ways.But one thing making me annoyed is that i can't add subscript(or superscript) in notion text block。Are there any fellows can handle this？ 
as shown：
[text with subscript i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UazEn.png)

[when i edit in notion block i get like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4C85.png)

Comment: Please provide some more details. Like what you have tried so far? What is your desired output?

Comment: @Nabil Farhan ，i have add two picture as detail

Comment: I got a reply from the notion offically that they do not support this so far

Answer (score 22):

**For subscript:**

```
/math
```

Then `C_1` renders C<sub>1</sub>

**For superscript:**

```
/math
```

Then `C^2` renders C<sup>2</sup>

Answer (score 17):

In the latest version as of writing, you could use:

1. `$$c^2$$` - for superscript
2. `$$c_2$$` - for subscript

If you write any mathematical equation between `$$ $$`, it will render beautifully on notion.

Answer (score 7):

**For more than 1 character superscript**

```
/math
P^{xyz}
```

Result: **P<sup>xyz</sup>**

**For more than 1 character subscript**

```
/math
P_{xyz}
```

Result: **P<sub>xyz</sub>**

In fact, this works for 1 or many characters as subscript or superscript.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stumbling upon this question who does not want to write math equations but simply wants to add a couple of superscript or exponent elements to a Notion page, for instance to write footnotes: there seems to be no way to add "simple" superscript (inline and with the same font), but you can use superscript unicode characters, for instance with a tool such as this [one](https://lingojam.com/SuperscriptGenerator).

It is not perfect as many characters are not available, but will cover many¹ common² uses³ of superscriptᶜᶦᵗᵃᵗᶦᵒⁿ ⁿᵉᵉᵈᵉᵈ.

Answer (score 1):

Even I just started using notion and faced the same problem. The solution I found was to keep a tab of laTex containing the syntax for all the required math formulae open. It is only temporary as you will get used to them pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

In Notion, there are two ways to add math formulas: `inline equations` and `block equations`. Both use KaTeX formatting to show the formulas. KaTeX is a TeX display formulas method based on JavaScrpt language. When you place a block or inline equation, for your example, you have to do something like that in the code:

```
w_{1}=0 ~,~ w_{2}=1
```

Note that spaces are not rendered, you gotta use ~ separate things, and the { } on these subscripts are optional because when not placed, *the "_" will take just the first next character when it is not placed the brackets*. To do superscript, change the "_" to "^". You can combine both in the same main variable, like `w_2^2=1`.

In the following links, you can see a Notion's guide about how to use it, the supported features KaTeX allows you to do, and a link to easy creating formulas.

### Notion:

https://www.notion.so/help/math-equations

### KaTeX Supported Functions:

https://katex.org/docs/supported.html or
https://katex.org/docs/support_table.html

### Easy web TeX editor:

https://atomurl.net/math/

Take time to try and explore writing by typping. Then, when you get used to it, it flows easily like writing regular text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tex to write things is superscript or subscript or basically any type of formulae , but its still in tex.

Answer (score 0):

I did and worked on my Notion

Step 1: Choose what to add subscript(or superscript) in notion block (Example a^n)

Step 2: Choose symbol sqrt(x)

Step 3: Press "Done"